# Why is my UPDATE stored procedure executed multiple times?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use stored procedures to manage a warehouse. PDA scanners scan the added stock and send it in bulk (when plugged back) to a SQL database (SQL Server 2016).

The SQL database is fairly remote (other country), so there's sometimes delay in some queries, but this particular one is problematic: even if the stock table is fine, I had some problems with **updating the occupancy of the warehouse spots**. The PDA tracks the added items in every spot as a SMALLINT, then send back this value to the stored procedure below.

PDA "send_spots" query:

```
SELECT spot, added_items FROM spots WHERE change=1
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_spots]
@spot VARCHAR(10),
@added_items SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE storage_spots
    SET remaining_capacity = remaining_capacity - @added_items
    WHERE storage_spot=@spot
    IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN - 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRAN
        RETURN 0
    END
END
GO
```

If the `remaining_capacity` value is 0, the PDAs can't add more items to it on next round. But with this process, I had **negative values because the query allegedly ran two times** (so subtracted `@added_items` two times).

Is there a way for that to be possible? How could I fix it? From what I understood the transaction should be cancelled (ROLLBACK) if the affected rows are != 1, but maybe that's something else.

EDIT: current solution with the help of @Zero:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_spots]
    @spot VARCHAR(10),
    @added_racks SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Recover current capacity of the spot
    DECLARE @orig_capacity SMALLINT
    SELECT TOP 1
        @orig_capacity = remaining_capacity
    FROM storage_spots
    WHERE storage_spot=@spot

    -- Test if double is present in logs by comparing dates (last 10 seconds)
    DECLARE @is_double BIT = 0
    SELECT @is_double = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT *
    FROM spot_logs
    WHERE log_timestamp >= dateadd(second, -10, getdate()) AND storage_spot=@spot AND delta=@added_racks)
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN
        UPDATE storage_spots
        SET remaining_capacity= @orig_capacity - @added_racks
        WHERE storage_spot=@spot

        IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 OR @is_double <> 0
            -- If double, rollback UPDATE
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        ELSE
            -- If no double, commit UPDATE
            COMMIT TRAN

        -- write log
        INSERT INTO spot_logs
            (storage_spot, former_capacity, new_capacity, delta, log_timestamp, double_detected)
        VALUES 
            (@spot, @orig_capacity, @orig_capacity-@added_racks, @added_racks, getdate(), @is_double)
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: You should be checking whatever code is calling this procedure, because the procedure seems fine. To test it try running this procedure directly and see if it does it twice (it should only do it once).

Comment: What measures have you got in place to ensure the added_items being passed in is not greater than the remaining_space in the db.  Remaining_space = 5, added_items passed in = 10, this will update remaining_space to -5 without the proc running twice.

Comment: If you were to implement an audit table - i.e. recording details of each UPDATE (value, datetime , user etc) this would be much easier to diagnose as its likely how the system is being used (concurrent changes for example) rather than an issue with the database logic itself.

Comment: *Remaining_space = 5, added_items passed in = 10, remaining_space to -5*
This case is not possible because the PDA app ensures that you can't scan more than the remaining space.

There's a case where two (or more) PDA could each add items to overflow the *remaining_space* value, but the physical space would be full before.

Comment: default isolation level?

Comment: @Zero I'm only able to do tests on my dev server, and this has been going fine. The production server, which is out of the country, possibly has connection issues that result in the current problem.

Comment: Doesn't address your immediate problem (that you've got two separate processes for reading and updating your data and no transaction to ensure *consistency*), but I'd usually model this as the slots have a fixed *capacity* and then recording against items the slot they occupy and their volume/capacity usage. `remaining_capacity` is *derived* data from those two. Storing derived data just offers the opportunity for it to be inconsistent (with other data, with reality, etc)

Comment: You should really 'queue' up the changes in a log / staging table, then apply that log, rather than updating the table directly. Based on the info provided there is no clue as to what is really happening.

Comment: Maybe a user was able to submit his records twice. Or the updates came from different PDAs?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever initially we only used the `initial_capacity` value and an `current_items` value, but when people started to use two or more PDAs to work on the same container, we went with the current system of `remaining_capacity`/`added_items`

Comment: @WolfgangK from our audit this morning, the records were submitted twice by the same PDA/same user, but this happened multiple times last night. Users aren't capable of submitting twice their records (they are sent back to the home menu after sync), so there was some SQL bug involved (maybe PDA/C#, but I doubt it)

Comment: Do you somewhere set `change = 0` in your local PDA database?

Comment: @WolfgangK the `change` value is a BIT defaulted to 0 (in the table definition), so I don't have to provide it when I import the remote data on the PDA. Every spot starts with `change=0` then, if an item is scanned on a particular spot, it becomes `change=1`. This way, I only send back spots that were modified.

Comment: That's what I thought, but after sending the modifications, how do you ensure that the "modofocation flag" is reset before the next synchronization occurs?

Comment: @WolfgangK I automatically execute a `DELETE FROM spots` query to clear the tables after the data is sent, and the users have to acquire all the data again. Not ideal but it ensures that PDAs have the most recent data.

Comment: use a validation script to make sure it only runs once

Comment: @jldjul So Maybe this deletion from spots went wrong, if so then probably due to a lack of permissions for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about possible causes (and a way to trace them) and then it hit me - you have no value validation!

Here's a simple example to illustrate the problem:

```
 Spot | capacity 
 ---------------
  x1  |     1

Update spots set capacity = capacity - 2 where spot = 'X1'
```

Your scanner most likely gave you higher quantity than you had capacity to take in.
I am not sure how your business logic goes, but you need to perform something in lines of

```
Update spots set capacity = capacity - @added_items where spot = 'X1' and capacity  >= @added_items
if @@rowcount <> 1;
   rollback;
```

---

EDIT: few methods to trace your problem without implementing validation:
Create a logging table (with `timestamp`, `user id` (user, that is connected to DB), `session id`, `old value`, `new value`, `delta value` (added items).

---

**Option 1:**
Log all updates that change value from positive to negative (at least until you figure out the problem).
The drawback of this option is that it will not register double calls that do not result in a negative capacity.

---

**Option 2:** (logging identical updates):
Create script that creates a global temporary table and deletes records, from that table timestamps older than... let's say 10 minutes once every minute or so (play around with numbers).

This temporary table should hold the data passed to your update statement so 'spot', 'added_items' + 'timestamp' (for tracking).
Now the crucial part: When you call your update statement check if a similar record exists in the temporary table (same spot and added_items and where current timestamp is `between timestamp and [timestamp + 1 second]` - again play around with numbers). If a record like that exist log that update, if not add it to temporary table.

This will register identical updates that go within 1 second of each other (or whatever time-frame you choose).

Comment: I purposefully have no value validation because I wanted the warehouse guys to be able to add more items than possible THEN correct it when they realize the physical capacity was overloaded.

However I didn't accounted for my current multiple execution problem, so this might be the solution (even if the client won't like it).

The fact is that with occasionally connected devices there's no perfect solution, but I'll try your thing.

Comment: In that case, do something different: Create a logging table for that 1 function and log old, new value and delta value (added_items) (and `user id` + `session id` + `timestamp`) every time you update from a positive to negative. That way you will be able to check if and when your function is ever called twice and produces a negative result. Do that at least until you make sure if that problem is a problem or just the issue of lack of validation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna go with your 2nd option, seems promising. I have to wait for it to be deployed in production, so I'll see tomorrow if it has logged identical updates (I added 'userid' and 'pda_id' to be safe). The UPDATE problems happened at night (~1AM this morning) so maybe there's a link with server availability at this hour.

Comment: "option 2" did the trick, thanks! We were able to log all double records and use those logs to rollback the UPDATES, all without changing the PDA's code. I'll edit my original post with the final stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/388113/sql-stored-procedure-subtract-or-add-to-value) an alternative SQL query that does the update the way I need, but with a temporary value using DECLARE. Would it work better in my case, or is my initial query correct?

Initial query:

```
UPDATE storage_spots
    SET remaining_capacity = remaining_capacity - @added_items
    WHERE storage_spot=@spot
```

Alternative query:

```
DECLARE @orig_capacity SMALLINT
SELECT TOP 1 @orig_capacity = remaining_capacity 
    FROM storage_spots 
    WHERE spot=@spot
UPDATE Products 
    SET remaining_capacity = @orig_capacity - @added_items 
    WHERE spot=@spot
```

Also, should I get rid of the ROLLBACK/COMMIT instructions?

Comment: As far as I know, it does exact same thing and a general rule for transaction statements: If you perform more than 1 DB action (select and update in your case) - use transactions.  For instance you should rollback if select fails (if it doesn't select anything @orig_capacity will be null and cause an exception.